# Can’t push to Gitlab registry | Quarkus - Jib build

Tags: gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci, quarkus, jib

I'm currently developing Quarkus applications and need therefore a CI Pipeline + Container Registry.

As containerization through docker isn't working (docker daemon - priviliged mode) I want to use Jib, which is already supported by Quarkus.

Command in Pipeline:

```
- mvn clean package 
-Dquarkus.container-image.push=true 
-Dquarkus.container-image.registry="https://$registry" 
-Dquarkus.container-image.username=$username 
-Dquarkus.container-image.password=$deployToken 
-Dquarkus.container-image.name=(group)/(project)
```

- username = deploy token username
- password = deploy token

The deploy token has all permissions there are, so that should not be the problem.

I also tried different variants of the command where I added the token in the registry url:

- https://username:token@registry.gitlab.com(group)/(project)
- https://name:token@registry.gitlab.com(group)/(project)

but in those cases obvious without these params:

- Dquarkus.container-image.username=$username
- Dquarkus.container-image.password=$deployToken

But I got everytime the same respone:

```
Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.7.2.Final:build (default) on project (project): 
Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.container.image.jib.deployment.JibProcessor#buildFromJar threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
The supplied container-image registry 'https://registry.gitlab.com/(group)/(project)' is invalid
```

I really hope that somebody has an idea, what is going wrong here.

---

In an other project I also used Jib to containerize a spring boot application and push it to the Google Container Registry, which is working when I use the Google SDK in advance.

```
- gcloud auth activate-service-account (account-name) --key-file=$gsdk_token
- gcloud auth configure-docker
```

Is there maybe a similar approach possible for the Gitlab Registry?

Comment: Can you take a look at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8588 and comment there if the issue is similar? It certainly looks like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown by [this code](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/8229f0072d6afa22eb82328749ea1ab294154606/extensions/container-image/container-image-jib/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/container/image/jib/deployment/JibProcessor.java#L220) based on [this check](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/dbc5b7d58532f6fd21c53faf394f68ecbf40d8fd/jib-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/jib/api/ImageReference.java#L218). The "registry" string should in the form of, say,

```
some.registry.host.example.com[:optional_port]
```

Therefore, in your case, it should be

```
-Dquarkus.container-image.registry=registry.gitlab.com
```

And I also noticed that Quarkus once enforced a [very rigid format](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8117#issuecomment-603703875) for an image reference (which I don't know is resolved as of now); you'll need to consult the [Quarkus plugin doc](https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image#quarkus-container-image_configuration) to see how you can properly format the final image reference.

Also see these other Quarkus issues:

- https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8588
- https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8117

---

Bonus for Jib users:

It is great that Quarkus internally utilizes the [Jib Core library](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-core) (the same library that powers the Jib Maven/Gradle build plugins) to build a container image. But for those interested, the Jib build plugins also have Jib Quarkus extensions ([Maven](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/master/first-party/jib-quarkus-extension-maven)/[Gradle](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/master/first-party/jib-quarkus-extension-gradle)) that directly containerize Quarkus apps.

Comment: Now its working. 
I completly overlooked the -Dquarkus.container-image.group=$group option. + -Dquarkus.container-image.registry=registry.gitlab.com was the way to go.
Thanks a lot man!